# Sympy gives a discontinuous solution to a simple ODE involving Piecewise

Tags: python, sympy, ode

I am trying to solve a linear ODE with a rectangular signal as second member, for the first and second order :

[image: First order]
[image: Second order]

I define the second member with sympy.Piecewise. For The first order, Sympy gives the expecting result. But for the second order, the result is discontinuous. Sympy seems not to take y(5) as initial condition for the t>5 part.

[image: Result for the first order]         [image: Result for the second order]

How could I have a continuous solution ?

Here is my code :

```
python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sp

t = sp.symbols('t')
y = sp.Function('y')
f = sp.Function('f')


#%% First order
t = sp.symbols('t')
y = sp.Function('y')

f = sp.Piecewise((1, t<5), (0, True))
eq = sp.Eq(y(t).diff(t) + y(t), f)
ics = {y(0): 0}
sol = sp.dsolve(eq, ics=ics)

# plot
yl = sp.lambdify(t, sol.rhs, modules='numpy')
fl = sp.lambdify(t, f, modules='numpy')
t_val = np.linspace(0,10,500)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t_val, yl(t_val), label='y(t)')
plt.plot(t_val, fl(t_val), label='f(t)')
plt.title('first order', fontsize=30)
plt.legend(fontsize=20)

#%% Second order
t = sp.symbols('t')
y = sp.Function('y')

f = sp.Piecewise((1, t<5), (0, True))
eq = sp.Eq(sp.diff(y(t),t,t) + y(t) + sp.diff(y(t),t), f)
ics = {sp.diff(y(t),t).subs(t, 0): 0, y(0): 0}
sol = sp.dsolve(eq, ics=ics)

# plot
yl = sp.lambdify(t, sol.rhs, modules='numpy')
fl = sp.lambdify(t, f, modules='numpy')
t_val = np.linspace(0,10,500)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t_val, yl(t_val), label='y(t)')
plt.plot(t_val, fl(t_val), label='f(t)')
plt.title('Second order', fontsize=30)
plt.legend(fontsize=20)
```

Comment: I think that this is a bug in sympy. Best to report it on github: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: The bug more precisely is that the integral of piecewise functions is not continuous. You can work around that by using the jump of the sign function, `f =  5*(sp.sign(5-t)+1)/2`, this results in a correct piecewise function for the solution.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this change destroys the first case as the integrals are not solved.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I posted [this issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19208) on github.